# How to run a local docker image as a k3s node

Tags: docker, kubectl, k3s

I've just started with docker and k3s.

I have a local docker image that I've made with a custom app inside.

I was wondering how would I set that as a pod on k3s.

I have k3s set with docker instead of containerd but when I run kubectl create I still get the error ImagePullBackOff.

Can anyone help? thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the error about the image pull backoff?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it to work by reverting to containerd and following this guide: https://cwienczek.com/2020/06/import-images-to-k3s-without-docker-registry/
I'm now creating yaml files and uploading the dockerimages using ctr.

Answer (score 0):

Here a demo instructions I wrote in the past for a company demo:

**References**

- https://microk8s.io/docs
- https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-dns

**Install/Setup**

```sh
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.21  

sudo usermod -a -G microk8s $USER 
sudo chown -f -R $USER ~/.kube 
su - $USER 

# DNS setup

microk8s.kubectl run -i --tty --image busybox:1.28.4 dns-test --restart=Never --rm /bin/sh
```

microk8s enable registry dns storage

**Start**

```sh
sudo systemctl start docker 
microk8s start
```

**Services check**

```sh
microk8s status --wait-ready 

microk8s kubectl get nodes 
microk8s kubectl get services
```

**App deploy**

```sh
# Pull hello world image from docker hub

docker pull hello-world 

# Push hello world image to microk8s registry

docker tag hello-world localhost:32000/hello-world 
docker push localhost:32000/hello-world 

# Try it

docker run --rm localhost:32000/hello-world
```

**App running**

```sh
microk8s kubectl run my-demo --image localhost:32000/hello-world 
microk8s kubectl expose pod my-demo --port 8080 --target-port 8080
```

**Terminatation**

```sh
microk8s kubectl delete service my-demo 
microk8s kubectl delete pod my-demo 

# or  

kubectl delete -f app.yaml 

# then 

microk8s.stop
```

Comment: I've done a similar thing with pushing the dockerimage and retrieving it successfully. However, when I run kubectl run it still cannot get the image returning the ErrImagePull and then the ImagePullBackOff

Comment: I don't which is the problem of your envirnoment unfortunately, but my demo worked for me.